# netlogo in a autonomous java executable

Tags: java, executable, netlogo

In Netbeans, I am able to run NetLogo and to transfer data to another java program (two differents threads).

Now, I would like to build a executable java program in order to use it as-is.

The problem is I have the following error message when I launch the exe:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at org.nlogo.awt.EventQueue$.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.scala:19)
    at org.nlogo.app.App$.main(App.scala:157)
    at org.nlogo.app.App.main(App.scala)
    at emulateur.Emulateur_ec.main(Emulateur_ec.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.TraversableLike.collect(Lscala/PartialFunction;Lscala/collection/generic/CanBuildFrom;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.nlogo.swing.ToolBar.addNotify(ToolBar.scala:44)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.pack(Unknown Source)
    at org.nlogo.swing.MessageDialog.<init>(MessageDialog.java:57)
    at org.nlogo.window.RuntimeErrorDialog.<init>(RuntimeErrorDialog.java:109)
    at org.nlogo.window.RuntimeErrorDialog.init(RuntimeErrorDialog.java:35)
    at org.nlogo.app.App.org$nlogo$app$App$$finishStartup(App.scala:426)
    at org.nlogo.app.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(App.scala:157)
    at org.nlogo.swing.Implicits$$anon$17.run(Implicits.scala:12)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I understand that the "java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait" error line is here because of the following lines at the beginning of the java program

```
App.main (ch);
appli = App.app();
try 
{
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait
    ( 
        new Runnable ()
        { 
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    App.app().open(...);
                }
                catch (java.io.IOException ex ) 
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace ();
                }
            } 
        } 
    )
};
```

But I really do not know how to solve it!

To build the executable, I included (as in the netbeans projects) the NetLogo.jar and NetLogoLite.jar

Thank you for your advoices!
cocq

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1) Remove `NetLogoLite.jar` from the classpath. `NetLogoLite.jar` exists *only* for use in applets; having it on the classpath in any other scenario will only hurt, never help.

2) Add *all* of the library jars in NetLogo's `lib` directory to your classpath.

To accomplish #2, it should only be necessary to put a copy of the entire `lib` directory in the same location as the copy of NetLogo.jar you are using. NetLogo.jar's manifest has a classpath entry that looks for the supporting jars at relative pathnames beginning with `lib/`.  But if you aren't able to get it to work that way — and I'm not familiar with NetBeans or with classpath setup in IDE's in general, so I don't know whether to expect any difficulty in that specific context — then explicitly adding every jar in that directory to the classpath should work also.

Comment: It's allright. The solution was to remove NetLogoLite.jar from the exe4j project (the used software to build the java executable). There were not any problems in Netbeans, but the conflict exists to build java executable. Thanks!